# Why does the clock stay at high?

Tags: i2c, clock

I'm very new and I'm trying to do an I2C trace of ADXL345 with Ch1 to SCL and Ch2 to SDA, but the traces look like these:

[image]

[image]

Is the clock not supposed to oscillate continuously? Is it normal for it to stay high when data is being written (although the decoder fails to decode).

I wonder if I'm doing something wrong and missing something basic.

Comment: I'd say you've got a problem somewhere :), activity on SCK & SDA should definitely occur at the same time, in the same bursts of activity.  That your "decoder" (whatever it is) isn't working is further evidence of this. Are you bit-banging this I2C interface,or using a dedicated I2C peripheral in your microcontroller to do this?

Comment: @Techydude Yes, I'm bit banging here. I'm building on the BMP180 I2C implementation at https://github.com/reaper7/esp8266_i2c_bmp180/blob/master/i2c_bmp180.c

Comment: What functions are you calling for what is seen on the scope ? You using the recommended i2c library mentioned in the readme ?

Comment: If you've never bit-banged a serial protocol before, then I suspect you've got yourself "temporally confused" in how your code is actually executing.  What's your hardware platform?  If you've got an I2C hardware peripheral there, use it - learn to walk before you try to run.  If not, then leverage countless other bit=banged I2C implementations.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed you're on the ESP8266 platform, which has no hardware I2C peripheral - hence the need to bit-bang.  Alarmingly, the I2C bit-banging driver you're relying on: https://github.com/zarya/esp8266_i2c_driver says "This driver is far from perfect and still needs work", so there's a hint :)

Comment: To answer some specific questions, SCK doesn't oscillate "continuously", only when each bit within a byte within an I2C packet is being sent, or received.  As the master on the I2C bus, when bit-banging, basically you turn SDA into an output, drive it high or low for the state of the bit you wish to transmit, then bring your SCL low, then release it back to high. Rinse & repeat for each bit. To receive the response from your I2C peripheral, make SDA an input, then drive SCK low, read the state of SDA (as driven by the I2C slave device), then release SCH back to high. rinse & repeat.

Comment: There is quite a bit more to I2C than that, and it all has to be done within the timing constraints of the I2C spec (which in turn will be determined by the bus speed you need to operate at, which will be determined by the peripheral you're driving - 100kHz, 400kHz, etc.

Comment: Indeed, I actually made a very basic mistake! I didn't initialise I2C. Silly me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, given that you're bit-banging I2C on a microcontroller that's undoubtedly got "other things to do" (wifi on the 8266, right?), it's possible your bit-banged I2C program flow is being interrupted to handle wifi (or who knows what else), and possibly screwing things up.  Perhaps you (the Zarya I2C library you're using) needs to be disabling interrupts for the duration of each I2C byte, or even each entire transaction to/from your I2C peripheral.  You don't want to be interrupted part way through a byte: the I2C peripheral might time-out, but your bit-banged code is still 'in state' in the middle of a byte & has no idea xx mS just passed between a couple of its bits transmissions/receivings.

Answer (score 0):

The I2C clock should be 1 when idle. Refer to the I2C stop condition. If you use a bit-banging function, Google existing examples, don't reinvent the wheel. And of course it's always better to use on-chip peripherals.